# JTable mouse click event returns old value after filter

Tags: java, filter, jtable

I'm familiarizing myself with JTable filtering for a project I'm working on to enhance my java knowledge.

I'm facing a problem with the values that are being returned once I click on the table after applying a filter by a String value read from a JTextField.
For example if I click a row from the original data, let's say (row 2), the values returned will be the full path and target, which are correct As shown in the ***Orignal table data image*** (Image 1)

However, after filtering let's say by **taget** as shown in ***filtered table data image*** (Image 2) the values returned are the path of **src** project name.

If not mistaken, it has something to do with the table model after filtering.

[image: Orignal table data]

[image: Filterd table data]

```
    // Code to retrieve selected rows
    public String[] getClickedProject(JTable table) {
            String[] projectPathAndName = new String[2];
            int selectRowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
            projectPathAndName[0] = table.getModel().getValueAt(selectRowIndex, 0).toString().trim();
            projectPathAndName[1] = table.getModel().getValueAt(selectRowIndex, 1).toString().trim();
            return projectPathAndName;
        }

// Code to filter table
public void filterTableByProject(JTable table, String projectName) {
        DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(defaultTableModel);
        table.setRowSorter(tableRowSorter);
        tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(projectName));
        
    }
```

I would appreciate any help/pointers, or sample code

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing `table.getModel().getValueAt(selectRowIndex, 0).toString().trim();` with `table.getValueAt(selectRowIndex, 0).toString().trim();`

My analysis, correct me if I'm wrong please, since I was using `table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column)` to retrieve the value, it was using the original table model, whereas using `table.getValueAt(row, column)` automatically updates the table model and uses the filtered table

Comment: Nope `table.getValueAt` does not update the model, it just does the conversion I commented above. Also [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt(int,int)): "**Note:** The column is specified in the table view's display order, and not in the TableModel's column order. This is an important distinction because as the user rearranges the columns in the table, the column at a given index in the view will change. Meanwhile the user's actions never affect the model's column ordering."

Comment: Oh alright thank you for the explanation, so it's that the data is not sorted/removed from the TableModel. I only see the sorted/filtered view of the data. Therefore I no longer have a one-to-one mapping of the "table row" and the "model row" correct?

Comment: exactly, you don't want data being removed from the model just for filtering  - eventually you may want to change the filter